# Visual Studio says "Method must have a return type"

Tags: c#, methods, spritebatch

It says

> "Method must have a return type"

whenever I try to debug it.

I don't know how to fix this class

This is a player class for a c# coded 2d Game

```
public class player
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Texture2D texture;

    //default constructer
    public Player(Texture2D tex, Vector2 startPos)
    {
        position  = startPos;
        texture   = tex;
        moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //------------------------------------------
        //check for keyboard input(keyboard IF statements)

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, which line has the error?  Don't you think it would help to tell us?

Answer (score 23):

Your class is `player` but the constructor is `Player`, because they are different it is expecting `Player` to be a method rather than a constructor

Change the class name to `Player` and you will be good

Answer (score 11):

Your class name is `player` with lower case. When the compiler finds the constructor for class `Player` (upper case), it thinks it is a method called `Player` without a return type specified.

So simply rename your class to uppercase `Player`. C# is case sensitive, so `player` and `Player` are two different things.

Answer (score 7):

Your class is lowercase player, your constructor is uppercase. Class name & Constructor should always be identical and are case-sensitive :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's a typo. Your class name is player is lower case and your constructor has a capital letter, so it's not seen as a cinstructor but as a method missing the void keyword.

EDIT: Sorry for what se4ems to be a repeated answer, seems like many people answered at almost the same moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is "player", but the constructor name is "Player" (uppercase of p). So the constructor is considered as a method without a return type. Rename it as "player" and it will work :)