# Appium with C#, method must have return type error

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I am getting 'Method must have a return type' whenever i tried to run this project. I would appreciate your help as i have been struggling to resolve this issue to no avail. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Enums;
using System.Threading;
```

namespace AppiumTest
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            AppiumDriver driver;

```
        TestMethod1()
        {


            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.deviceName", "Test");
            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.deviceName", "Test");
            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.platformVersion", "Emulator");
            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.platformName", "Android");

            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.appPackage", "");
            capabilities.SetCapability("MobileCapabilityType.appActivity", "");

            driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1.4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElementById("com.paypoint.energycontrols:id/btn_sign_in").Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.paypoint.energycontrols:id/et_email")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.paypoint.energycontrols:id/et_password")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElementById("com.paypoint.energycontrols:id/btn_show_pass").Click();
            driver.FindElementById("com.paypoint.energycontrols:id/btn_sign_in").Click();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio says"Method must have a return type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739932/visual-studio-saysmethod-must-have-a-return-type)

Comment: Surely you googled the error message and learned what the error message meant and tried all the possible fixes you could find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method declaration has only method name. In C# methods must have return type and a name. Add a `void` keyword before `TestMethod1()`:

```
void TestMethod1() { ... }
```

Comment: I added the void as you suggested and that cleared the error but when i run the test, i got the below 2 errors. Severity Code 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidDriver<OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumWebElement>' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver<OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidElement>' AppiumTest C:\temp\AppiumTest\AppiumTest\Class1.cs 37 Active

Comment: Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point AppiumTest C:\temp\AppiumTest\AppiumTest\CSC 1 Active

Comment: @tutade for you last error - add  new metod `static void Main() { ... }` and call `TestMethod1()` there